# Problemas com renderização Vue Router 4 + Vue 3 (versão de compatibilidade)

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-router

#### Contexto

Estou migrando minha aplicação de vue 2 para vue 3, e estou usando a versão de compatibilidade ([migration build](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/migration-build.html)).
Minha aplicação é uma WebExtension (extensão de navegador).

##### Fluxo da aplicação

- Manifest.json chama a função(make-spa.js) para incluir uma div.
- Make-spa.js cria uma div e insere um shadowRoot após chama a função (app.js)
- App.js é onde é montado o Vue 3 juntamente com o Router

#### Problema

A aplicação renderiza mas o router-view não funciona. porém se usar um console.log( useRouter().path) ele mostra o console.

#### O que eu já tentei

- Segui a documentação do guia de migração
- Tentei usar o modo de compatibilidade de vue 3 apenas para o router
- Tentei usar todos os componentes em vue 3
- Atualizei a versão do node para 16
- Tentei simplificar a aplicação para usar apenas dois componentes sem nenhum requisito que poderia atrapalhar.
- Tentei alterar os modos de history do router
- Tentei importar o router-view do vue-router diretamente no componente
- Tentei renderizar sem o shadow root

#### Códigos para analisar o problema

```
"devDependencies": {
...,
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.1.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.4",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.62.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.4.1",
    "vue-loader": "^16.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-extension-reloader": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@kyvg/vue3-notification": "^2.9.1",
    "@vue/compat": "^3.1.0",
    "vue": "^3.1.0",
    "vue-custom-element": "^3.2.14",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0"
  }
```

```js
// app.js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import Teste from './Teste.vue';
import { createRouter, createMemoryHistory } from 'vue-router';
import TesteStart from './TesteStart.vue';


let router = createRouter({
  history: createMemoryHistory(),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: TesteStart,
    }
  ]
});

let element = document.getElementById('cpn-wrapper')?.shadowRoot.getElementById('cuponomia');

const app = createApp(Teste);
app.use(router);
app.mount(element);
```

Teste.vue

```js
<template>
  <div>
    Teste
    <br />
    <router-view></router-view>
    <br />
    Teste
  </div>
</template>
<script setup></script>
<style></style>
```

TesteStart.vue

```js
<template>
  <div>Teste Start</div>
</template>
<script setup>
</script>
```